# How to add a custom RESTful route to a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, routes

I'm reading these two pages

1. [`resources`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Resources.html#M000522)
2. [`Adding more RESTful actions`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions)

The Rails Guides page shows

```
map.resources :photos, :new => { :upload => :post }
```

And its corresponding URL

```
/photos/upload
```

This looks wonderful.

---

My `routes.rb` shows this

```
map.resources :users, :new => { :signup => :get, :register => :post }
```

When I do: `[~/my_app]$ rake routes`

I see the two new routes added

```
  signup_new_user GET    /users/new/signup(.:format)
register_new_user POST   /users/new/register(.:format)
```

**Note** the inclusion of `/new`! I **don't** want that. I just want `/users/signup` and `/users/register` (as described in the Rails Routing Guide).

Any help?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

When you expose a controller as a resource, following actions are automatically added:

```
show
index
new
create
edit
update
destroy
```

These actions can be categorized in to two groups:

- `:member` actions

The URL for the member action has the id of the target resource. E.g:

```
users/1/edit 
users/1
```

You can think of `:member` action as an instance method on a class. It always applies on an existing resource.

Default member actions: `show`, `edit`, `update`, `destroy`

- `:collection` actions

The URL for the `:collection` action does not contain the id of the target resource. E.g:

```
users/login
users/register
```

You can think of `:collection` action as a static method on a class.

Default collection actions: `index`, `new`, `create`

In your case you need two new actions for registration. These actions belong to :collection type( as you do not have the id of the user while submitting these actions). Your route can be as follows:

```
map.resources :users, :collection => { :signup => :get, :register => :post }
```

The URL for the actions are as follows:

```
users/signup
users/register
```

If you want to remove a standard action generated by Rails use :except/:only options:

```
map.resources :foo, :only => :show

map.resources :foo, :except => [:destroy, :show]
```

**Edit 1**

I usually treat the `confirmation` action as a `:member` action. In this case `params[id]` will contain the confirmation code.

**Route configuration:**

```
map.resources :users, :member => { :confirm => :get}
```

**URL**

```
/users/xab3454a/confirm

confirm_user_path(:id => @user.confirmation_code) # returns the URL above
```

**Controller**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def confirm
    # assuming you have an attribute called `confirmation_code` in `users` table 
    # and you have added a uniq index on the column!!
    if User.find_by_confirmation_code(params[id])
      # success
    else
      # error
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: @KandadaBoggu, this explanation look great. As a follow-up to check for my understanding, say I wanted to send an "account confirmation" link in the user's welcome email. That link would contain an 8-character validation hash. Would I add `map.resources :users, :member => {:validate => :get}`? How does the `hash` param get plugged in?

Comment: Updated my answer, take a look.

Comment: What's telling `confirm_user_path` to use `@user.confirmation_code` in place of the `:id` wildcard instead of `@user.foo` or `@user.bar`? Should this be `confirm_user_path(:id => @user.confirmation_code)`?

Comment: @KandadaBoggu, just a note: StackOverflow says I can issue the bounty in 4 hours :)

Comment: Yes you have to use `confirm_user_path(:id => @user.confirmation_code)`, I will update the answer.

Comment: @KandadaBoggu, elegance as always. I will issue the bounty as soon as SO lets me :)

Answer (score 12):

This can be taken as just another syntax  -- something good to know may be.

**Syntax 1:**

```
resources :users do
  member do
    get 'signup'
    post 'register'
  end
end
```

Rake Route Output will include

```
signup_users GET    /users/signup(.:format)    {:action=>"signup", :controller=>"users"}
register_users POST   /users/register(.:format)  {:action=>"register", :controller=>"use
```

rs"}

**Syntax 2:** 
If you have only one collection route

```
resources :users do
    get 'signup', :on => :collection
end
```

Comment: I like the syntax 2, nice awnser

Answer (score 3):

If i'm understanding your question right, you just want to rename the urls of the `new` and `create` actions.

This would be done like so:

```
map.resources :users, :path_names => {:new => 'signup', :create => 'register'}
```

If you really would like to **add** new routes with corresponding controller actions, then Damiens answer is the way to go.

Comment: @mikezter, I definitely still need the `new` and `create` routes. However, this answers I question about *renaming* routes I've had in the past. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The `new` option allows you to create new routes for creating new objects. That's why they're prefixed with that term.

What you're looking for is the `:collection` option.

```
map.resources :users, :collection => { :signup => :get, :register => :post }
```

Which will create the `/users/signup` and `/users/register` urls.

Comment: I had trouble understand what `collection` was intended for. The route **is** for creating new objects; visitors that sign-up create a new `User` object. So, why wouldn't I want to use `new`? Is this a typo in the Rails Guide?